# Vertically align a list of equations with a figure

Tags: vertical-alignment

I found a lot of online content on how to manage alignment of tables, however none of it helped me to figure out the following.
I would like to show a figure with to the left of it a list of equations, which are centered vertically to the center of the figure. The code sample below is the minimal example of my best attempt so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash} l @{\qquad} r@{} }
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}

$y_1 = x$   \\
$y_2 = x^2$ \\
$y_3 = x^3$ \\
$y_4 = x^4$

\end{tabular} &
\includegraphics[scale=1.0, keepaspectratio = true]{picture.jpg}
\end{tabular}
\caption{How to align the center of the formulae with the image's center?}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which is giving the following output:

[image]

I use MikTeX with Texworks on a Windows machine. Any help on this matter will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You signature is automatically added at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabulars are naturally centered w.r.t the baseline, whereas pictures start with their bottom left corners on the baseline. It follows that using two tabulars stacked horizontally is easier than a single tabular and you will get the required result.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    $y_1 = x$   \\
    $y_2 = x^2$ \\
    $y_3 = x^3$ \\
    $y_4 = x^4$
  \end{tabular} \quad 
  \begin{tabular}{r@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm, keepaspectratio = true]{example-image}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{How to align the center of the formulae with the image's center?}
  \label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, accepted as the answer because the root of the problem is explained as well (implicitly @egreg did aswell).

Answer (score 4):

Use `amsmath` for the equations (here `aligned` is the best tool) and lower the picture by half its height.

In the example I added `\fbox{...}` around the image just to clearly show the bounding box.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

$\begin{aligned}
y_1 &= x   \\
y_2 &= x^2 \\
y_3 &= x^3 \\
y_4 &= x^4
\end{aligned}$\qquad
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{duck}}}
\caption{How to align the center of the formulae with the image's center?}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also a nice approach to this problem, feels more like a best practice rather than my tabular approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash} l @{\qquad} r@{} }
        \begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{}}    
            y_1 = x   \\
            y_2 = x^2 \\
            y_3 = x^3 \\
            y_4 = x^4               
        \end{tabular} &
        \adjustimage{valign=m}{picture.jpg}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Just use the package "adjustbox" here.}\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your approach, it is very nice to see so many different alternatives :)